# find command returns the current working directory as first output

Tags: linux, find, directory

I am using `find` against a number of directories that have in them the same filenames but different contents. Then, I am copying them to one directory with numerical filenames.

The problem I faced was that the `find` command reads the folders in different order than the `ls` command. Making it difficult to correlate the new files to their original directories.

My solution was to run the same `find` command on the original directories to get them in the same order and number them accordingly.

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's#./##' > rename.list
j=1
while read -r line
do
    mv ./"$line" ./"$j"_"$line"
    j=$(( $j + 1))
done < rename.list
```

This almost solved the problem, but the `find` command for some reason lists the current working directory as the first output which offsets the numbering by 1.

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's#./##'
.
dir2
dir1
dir3
```

although, the first `find` commands I ran did not have the same problem:

```
find . -wholename "*__substg1.0_007D001E*" -wholename "*attach_version*" -type d > header_files.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `-mindepth` option to `1` i.e. `-mindepth 1` to exclude the current directory (`.`) from `find`'s output:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d
```

Comment: This was exceedingly difficult to find the words to Google for, thank you very much